# Skip Git commit hooks

Tags: git, githooks, git-commit

I'm looking at a Git hook which looks for print statements in Python code.  If a print statement is found, it prevents the Git commit.

I want to override this hook and I was told that there is a command to do so.  I haven't been able to find it.  Any thoughts?

Comment: A solution that is more generic (also work for git commands different than `commit`): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58337861/disable-hooks-for-a-single-git-command

Comment: Related config: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54751668/git-pre-commit-hook-configuration - Modify your project root's `.pre-commit-config.yaml`

Answer (score 1744, accepted):

Maybe (from [`git commit` man page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit)):

```
git commit --no-verify -m "commit message"
           ^^^^^^^^^^^
-n  
--no-verify
```

> This option bypasses the pre-commit and commit-msg hooks. See also [githooks(5)](http://git-scm.com/docs/githooks).

As commented by [Blaise](https://stackoverflow.com/users/451480/blaise), `-n` can have a different role for certain commands.
For instance, [`git push -n`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-push) is actually a dry-run push.
Only `git push --no-verify` would skip the hook.

---

Note: Git 2.14.x/2.15 improves the `--no-verify` behavior:

See [commit 680ee55](https://github.com/git/git/commit/680ee550d72150f27cdb3235462eee355a20038b) (14 Aug 2017) by [Kevin Willford (``)](https://github.com/).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit c3e034f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c3e034f0f0753126494285d1098e1084ec05d2c4), 23 Aug 2017)</sup>

> ### `commit`: skip discarding the index if there is no `pre-commit` hook

> "`git commit`" used to discard the index and re-read from the filesystem
> just in case the `pre-commit` hook has updated it in the middle; this
> has been optimized out when we know we do not run the `pre-commit` hook.

---

[Davi Lima](https://stackoverflow.com/users/462849/davi-lima) points out [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7230820/skip-git-commit-hooks/7230886?noredirect=1#comment101929781_7230886) the [`git cherry-pick`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) does *not* support --no-verify.
So if a cherry-pick triggers a pre-commit hook, you might, as in [this blog post](http://web-dev.wirt.us/info/git-drupal/git-continue-vs-no-verify), have to comment/disable somehow that hook in order for your git cherry-pick to proceed.

The same process would be necessary in case of a `git rebase --continue`, after a merge conflict resolution.

---

With Git 2.36 (Q2 2022), the callers of `run_commit_hook()` to learn if it got "success" because the hook succeeded or because there wasn't any hook.

See [commit a8cc594](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a8cc594333848713b8e772cccf8159196ea85ede) (fixed with [commit 4369e3a1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4369e3a1a39895ab51c2bef2985255ad05957a20)), [commit 9f6e63b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9f6e63b966e9876ca6f990819fabafc473a3c9b0) (07 Mar 2022) by [Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason (`avar`)](https://github.com/avar).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 7431379](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7431379a9c5ed4006603114b1991c6c6e98d5dca), 16 Mar 2022)</sup>

> ### [`hooks`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a8cc594333848713b8e772cccf8159196ea85ede): fix an obscure **[TOCTOU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-of-check_to_time-of-use)** "did we just run a hook?" race
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason</sup>

> Fix a [**Time-of-check to time-of-use** (**TOCTOU**)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-of-check_to_time-of-use) race in code added in [680ee55](https://github.com/git/git/commit/680ee550d72150f27cdb3235462eee355a20038b) ("`commit`: skip discarding the index if there is no pre-commit hook", 2017-08-14, Git v2.15.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c3e034f0f0753126494285d1098e1084ec05d2c4) listed in [batch #3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ab86f93d680618f62ad6e3c2f37db76029cfce5e)).
>
> This obscure race condition can occur if we e.g. ran the "`pre-commit`" hook and it modified the index, but `hook_exists()` returns false later on (e.g., because the hook itself went away, the directory became unreadable, etc.).
> Then we won't call `discard_cache()` when we should have.
>
> The race condition itself probably doesn't matter, and users would have been unlikely to run into it in practice.
> This problem has been noted on-list when [680ee55](https://github.com/git/git/commit/680ee550d72150f27cdb3235462eee355a20038b) [was discussed](https://lore.kernel.org/git/20170810191613.kpmhzg4seyxy3cpq@sigill.intra.peff.net/), but had not been fixed.
>
> Let's also change this for the push-to-checkout hook.
> Now instead of checking if the hook exists and either doing a push to checkout or a push to deploy we'll always attempt a push to checkout.
> If the hook doesn't exist we'll fall back on push to deploy.
> The same behavior as before, without the TOCTOU race.
> See [0855331](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0855331941b723b227e93b33955bbe0b45025659) ("`receive-pack`: support push-to-checkout hook", 2014-12-01, Git v2.4.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cba07bb6ff58da5aa4538c4a2bbf70b717b172b3)) for the introduction of the previous behavior.
>
> This leaves uses of `hook_exists()` in two places that matter.
> The "reference-transaction" check in [`refs.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/a8cc594333848713b8e772cccf8159196ea85ede/refs.c), see [6754159](https://github.com/git/git/commit/675415976704459edaf8fb39a176be2be0f403d8) ("`refs`: implement reference transaction hook", 2020-06-19, Git v2.28.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/33a22c1a88d8e8cddd41ea0aa264ee213ce9c1d7) listed in [batch #7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4a0fcf9f760c9774be77f51e1e88a7499b53d2e2)), and the "prepare-commit-msg" hook, see [66618a5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/66618a50f9c9f008d7aef751418f12ba9bfc6b85) ("`sequencer`: run 'prepare-commit-msg' hook", 2018-01-24, Git v2.17.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1772ad1125a6f8a5473d73bbd17162bb20ebd825) listed in [batch #2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b2e45c695d09f6a31ce09347ae0a5d2cdfe9dd4e)).
>
> In both of those cases we're saving ourselves CPU time by not preparing data for the hook that we'll then do nothing with if we don't have the hook.
> So using this `"invoked_hook"` pattern doesn't make sense in those cases.
>
> The "`reference-transaction`" and "`prepare-commit-msg`" hook also aren't racy.
> In those cases we'll skip the hook runs if we race with a new hook being added, whereas in the TOCTOU races being fixed here we were incorrectly skipping the required post-hook logic.

Comment: For cherry-pick see http://web-dev.wirt.us/info/git-drupal/git-continue-vs-no-verify

Comment: @DaviLima Thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for visibility.

Comment: thanks, @Vonc. same happens for `git rebase --continue` btw

Comment: Hi, in my case, someone in my team keep updating my `hook` folder with some pre-commit scripts, it is so annoying, is there a way I can prevent my `hook` folder to be overriden by git pull?

Comment: @Zennichimaro Maybe you can copy that repo hook folder elsewhere, and setup a post-merge hook (https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_post_merge) which will detect if the pull affect the repo hook folder, and will propose to copy its content to your local hook folder (outside of the repo): that way, you can at least control if you want your hooks overridden or not by what is pushed by your colleagues.

Comment: How to disable the hooks permanently for one specific repository?

Comment: @aagjalpankaj You could simply make sure it is not executable. Or rename it. In both cases, that would be done in the `specific repo/.git/hooks`

Comment: @VonC - I tried that but still facing the issue. Can you please look into this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62494323/npm-run-deploy-ignore-hooks

Comment: yep. Had to rename .git\hooks\pre-commit and rename it back afterwards. I'm surprised there isn't a flag to pass flags to commit

Answer (score 77):

With both `comment` and `no verify` without any further issue:

```
git commit -m "Some comments" --no-verify
```

Comment: @Moumit The command just works fine.  You might want to rephrase the sentence as this is little confusing.

Comment: Understood the concern changed it @PramodItagi

Comment: What do you mean by *"with no further issue"*? Can you elaborate? And what do you mean by *"with both comment and no verify"*? It would be fine to elaborate here in comments. And/or by editing your answer.

Comment: ["-m" is *"Use the given <msg> as the commit message."*](https://linux.die.net/man/1/git-commit). By comment, do you mean the (commit) message?

Answer (score 55):

`--no-verify` works, but in my case, I didn't want to put the parameter all the time on the terminal. So I opted for something a little more aggressive.

If you want to disable `git hooks` globally, you could try running this:

```
git config --global core.hooksPath /dev/null
```

But, if you want to leave it as it was before, just run the following command in your terminal:

```
git config --global --unset core.hooksPath
```

If you do not want it to be global, just remove the argument: `--global`

I tested it with Git 2.16.3.

Comment: Thanks Francisco! Works like a charm! I ended up adding the following aliases to my `$HOME/.gitconfig` -> 
`disable-hooks = config core.hooksPath /dev/null` and `enable-hooks = config --unset core.hooksPath`.

Answer (score 34):

From `man githooks`:

> pre-commit
>          This hook is invoked by git commit, and can be bypassed with --no-verify option. It
>          takes no parameter, and is invoked before obtaining the proposed commit log message
>          and making a commit. Exiting with non-zero status from this script causes the git
>          commit to abort.

Answer (score 28):

*-n* or *--no-verify* does not work for a commit after 'git merge --continue' for example.

So here is another rougher idea.

1. Just **comment lines in file** `.git/hooks/pre-commit` with symbol '#'.
2. Run single or many commands
3. Uncomment
4. Profit.

Answer (score 16):

For some reason, `--no-verify` does not work for me with this particular hook: `prepare-commit-msg`

If you too are running into this issue, try:

```bash
SKIP=prepare-commit-msg git commit
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. Is the `SKIP` env var documented by git? Or is this some special control flow implemented by your `prepare-commit-msg` script?

Comment: @Jasha: it's not a Git standard thing.

Comment: I think this `SKIP` is part of the [pre-commit](https://pre-commit.com) tool and not part of core Git. See: https://pre-commit.com/index.html#temporarily-disabling-hooks

Answer (score -4):

SOB=$(git var GIT_AUTHOR_IDENT | sed -n 's/^(.*>).*$/- signed-off-by: \1/p')
grep -qs "^$SOB" "$1" || echo "$SOB" >> "$1"

Comment: This “signed-off-by” stuff is irrelevant. Did you reply to the wrong answer? Although it’s been half a week since I first saw this answer so you should have noticed by now.