# Is there a way to bypass post-merge git hook when executing `git merge` command

Tags: git, merge, hook, githooks

I have post-merge hook configured in order to integrate (semi-manually) with another version control system. However sometimes I would like to avoid the the hook from running is there some way to bypass it for `git merge`?

I knew there is `--no-verify` command line parameter for `git commit`. That kind of solution would be perfect for my use case but seems like  `--no-verify` is not working for `git commit` command.

Comment: You seem to be on the right track with `--no-verify`, q.v. [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7230820/skip-git-commit-hooks).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no flag to disable running a post-merge hook, but you could easily rig your own post-merge hook (which you control completely, since it's in your own repository) to obey an environment variable.  For instance, a shell script might start with:

```
#! /bin/sh
warn() {
    echo "warning: $1" 1>&2
}
case ${SKIP_POST_MERGE_HOOK:-no} in
yes) exit 0;;
no) ;;
*) warn "mystery value ${SKIP_POST_MERGE_HOOK} for SKIP_POST_MERGE_HOOK";;
esac
... rest of code as usual ...
```

Now if you want to run `git merge` but bypass the hook (or run something like the `git pull` convenience script that runs `git merge` for you), simply set `SKIP_POST_MERGE_HOOK=yes` for the duration:

```
$ SKIP_POST_MERGE_HOOK=yes git merge ...
```

Answer (score 23):

A simple approach (without having to alter config files) that worked for me is:

1. `git merge main`
2. Fix merge conflicts, if any
3. `git add .`
4. `git commit --no-verify`
5. `git push`

This is an example so you can definitely specify which files to add and add a commit message as well. I faced the same issue as the OP when trying to `git merge --continue`.

git version: 2.35.1

Comment: This is the answer we all came to look for

Comment: For anyone doing automation, I had to also add `--no-edit` to the commit step otherwise it would wait for an editor to close

Answer (score 19):

You can temporarily disable git hooks by doing the following:

```
$ git config core.hooksPath # to see the current value
$ git config core.hooksPath '/dev/null'
$ git merge --continue
$ git config core.hooksPath '/value/you/had/before'
```

Adapted from [this helpful answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67924079/5071753)

Comment: Thank you! After the `merge --continue` I had tho use `git config --unset core.hooksPath` because my `hooksPath` first returned nothing. You could add this to your answer.

Answer (score 16):

for those who came here because `git merge --no-verify --continue` doesn't work together - you can just disable hooks termporarily for the merge - e.g. for my current react project I just removed this part from my `package.json` - as file not staged it will not go into the merge commit

```
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
    }
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.{js,ts,tsx}": [
      "eslint --fix --rule '@typescript-eslint/no-non-null-assertion: error'",
      "prettier --write"
    ],
    "*.css": [
      "stylelint --fix",
      "prettier --write"
    ],
    "*.{json,yml,md,eslintrc,stylelintrc,babelrc}": [
      "prettier --write"
    ]
  },
```

Comment: if anyone's using `pre-commit`, I had to enable innocuous hooks, otherwise pre-commit complained about an invalid, and the merge would fail.

Answer (score 1):

I've done the trick by using the `GIT_REFLOG_ACTION` environment variable.

When using `git pull`, you'll find that `GIT_REFLOG_ACTION=pull` in your git hook.

Hence, you can do something like the following:

```
# if git pull, abort
if [[ $GIT_REFLOG_ACTION == "pull" ]]; then
  echo "git pull detected, aborting"
  exit 0
fi
```

I hope this can help!