# How do you `git cherry-pick --continue` with `--no-verify`?

Tags: git, git-cherry-pick

How do you `git cherry-pick --continue` with `--no-verify` since `--no-verify` is not a valid option.  `git cherry-pick --no-commit --continue` does not work since those two parameters are mutually exclusive.

Comment: `git cherry-pick --continue`? What context is this being used?

Comment: @evolutionxbox when you cherry-pick a range, typically.

Comment: Or when resolving conflicts

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`--no-verify` is an option for the `commit` command, not `cherry-pick`.

However what you *can* do is to use the `--no-commit` [flag](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick#Documentation/git-cherry-pick.txt---no-commit) for your `cherry-pick`, then `git commit --no-verify` is fine to conclude the cherry-pick.

Comment: --no-commit does not work with --continue though.  I'll add that to the OP to be more clear

Comment: You don't need `--continue` for the initial `cherry-pick` command. It's only useful after having handled the first cherry-picked commit (and until the sequence is over), to indicate to the sequencer that you're ready to process the next one in your series of commits.

Comment: This approach unfortunately won't work if the `git cherry-pick` induced conflicts that have to be resolved. In that case, after having resolved the conflicts, one only can use `git cherry-pick --continue` to resolve the cherry-pick, however, if the pre-commit hooks fail, one is stuck. The only option is to abort the cherry-pick and restart from scratch, including resolving the merge conflicts. Seems like this is not really what should be happening and there should be a way to disable the hooks temporarily when continuing an active cherry-pick.

Comment: @Pankrates I used this method on this exact scenario. I cherry-picked a range of commits, a few of the middle ones had conflicts (and were tripping my pre-commit hook). I just fixed the conflicts and did `git add`; `git commit` and then `git cherry-pick --continue`

Comment: +1 This is the correct answer. Just to reiterate what @RomainValeri mentioned: `git cherry-pick <SHA> --no-commit` and once you dealt with the conflicts and resolved them all, `git commit --no-verify`. It will only add the single commit intended.

Answer (score 42):

If your `cherry-pick` (without `--no-commit`) had merge conflicts and you want to `--continue` after solving them, you can temporarily disable git hooks for the current repo with:

```sh
$ git config core.hooksPath # Print current setting
$ git config core.hooksPath '/dev/null/'
```

After you're done, depending on whether `core.hooksPath` was set before, you can either restore the previous setting:

```sh
$ git config core.hooksPath '/some/previous/path'
```

or unset it again:

```sh
$ git config --unset core.hooksPath
```

Comment: It's unfortunate that this is the only solution

Comment: This should be the accepted answer!

Comment: For some reason, the above method didn't work for me (modifying the hooksPath via `git config`). Here's a work-around to the work-around: manually go into your `.git/hooks/` dir, rename the offending hooks, go back and finish the `cherry-pick --continue`, then rename the offending hooks back to their original names.

Comment: It is not the first or second time I gladly return to this reply and saves me time. Thankfully I had it bookmarked.

Answer (score 9):

Futher expading @teejay-bruno approach, what I did is:

```
pre-commit run
git -c core.hooksPath=/dev/null  cherry-pick --continue
```

This way I still run the verification even if some items fail, and cherry-pick without altering global configuration

Answer (score 7):

If all conflicts are resolved, then you don't need to `git cherry-pick --continue`.
Just `git commit --no-verify`. Then the process will be complete.

Comment: The cherry-pick continue creates a commit implictly. What you need is also the `--no-commit` flag for the cherry-pick command!

Comment: this is the answer

Answer (score 3):

To expand on @mickdekkers answer, I added the following function to my `~/.bashrc` --

```
git() {
    if [[ $@ == *"--no-verify"* ]];
    then
        command git -c core.hooksPath=/dev/null "$@ | sed 's/--no-verify//'";
    else
        command git "$@";
    fi;
}
```

This sets the hookpath to `null` any time the `--no-verify` flag is used.

Answer (score 2):

Yet another possible workaround would be to stash/un-stash before committing, as this will stop the cherry-pick operation so that the usual commit command can be used:

```
git stash
git stash pop
git add -u
git status
git commit -n
```

Answer (score 0):

Good question. To avoid touching git config or do complex stuff, a trick would be to **comment your pre-commit file**, then uncomment when cherry-picking is done.

Answer (score 0):

I just encounter some git conflicts while doing git cherry-pick.

After fixing and git add the required changes,
instead of `git cherry-pick --continue`, run `git commit -m "xxx" --no-verify` resolve it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).