# How to prevent eslint from blocking git commit?

Tags: git, eslint

I'm new to eslint and am using it to enforce coding style. However, when I write a `TODO` item into my code I get an eslint warning, alright that's fine. But, now when I try to git commit, it comes back with:

```
**** ESLint errors found :     
line 145, col 9, Warning - Unexpected 'todo' comment. (no-warning-comments)
```

How can I prevent eslint from blocking me from committing? I want it to still warn me about TODOs etc, but I would like to be able to commit my code as well.

Comment: Seems you have a pre-commit hook in .git/hooks. Either do `git commit --no-verify` or disable the hook completely.

Comment: That was it! I had a pre-commit hook.

Comment: Added as the answer for you to accept.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as duplicate of [Skip Git commit hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7230820/skip-git-commit-hooks)

Answer (score 116, accepted):

You have a pre-commit hook.

```
git commit --no-verify
```

allows to avoid it once. Or you can remove it completely from .git/hooks.

Answer (score 20):

Use --no-verify pre-commit hooks when commit.

```
git commit --no-verify -m "Commit message"
```

Answer (score 5):

In my case the culprit were `package.json` entries automatically created by a project creating CLI (`nuxt.js`). I removed from my `package.json` these entries:

```
"lint-staged": { ... },
"husky": { ... }
```

and it solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Usually warnings don't block commits only errors. If it's set to error you can switch it to warning, but looks like you may already have it set to warning.

```
"rules": {
 ...
 
 "no-warning-comments": 0,
 ...
}
```

The other option is to disable the rule for the given line

```
// eslint-disable-next-line no-warning-comments
// TODO disable eslint warning for this todo ;)
```

This would prevent the warning from showing up at all though

Otherwise you would need to look at what is being set up to prevent the commit, most likely something in your pre-commit hook located at `root/.git/hooks/pre-commit` and tell it to allow warnings and block errors

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

I navigated to my `.git/hooks` directory and found a pre-commit bash script. I changed the return value from 1 to 0 in the case where eslint failed and that solved the problem.

A 0 value represents a pass and will allow the commit to continue, a non-zero represents a fail state and will cancel the commit.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Starter Template like [Vitesse](https://github.com/antfu/vitesse) and also you want to remove those checks permanently follow these steps

Switch directory to your project then

```bash
pnpm rm simple-git-hooks
```

Delete unnecessary config in `package.json`

```json
{
  ...,
  "scripts": {
    ...,
    "postinstall": "npx simple-git-hooks"
  },
  ...,
  "simple-git-hooks": {
    "pre-commit": "pnpm lint-staged"
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "*": "eslint --fix"
  },
  ...
}
```

Remove those hooks existing

```bash
rm -rf .git/hooks
```