# How to create a pre-commit hook that will track errors from my Django code before I push to my server

Tags: python, django, git, version-control, pre-commit-hook

I've only recently found out what a pre-commit hook is, and from what I understand it's a file `(.git/hooks/pre-commit)` that tracks my code for errors before the changes are committed to my server (DigitalOcean). So I want to make this file but I don't know what code to add to it. I've tried to find example files of `pre-commit` for Django projects but cannot find any. Advice appreciated.

Comment: Since there is no magical "check all my code" command: what sbould be checked? Unit / integration / behavior tests? Code quality? Conventions? ...

Comment: I assume there's no way for it to behave like the Django debugger when working offline - so I guess I just want it to check for things like `print()` statements - things that work offline but shouldn't be added to a live production server.

Comment: It sounds like what you really want is some kind of continuous integration service life Travis which runs your tests on commit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what I understand it's a file (.git/hooks/pre-commit) that tracks my code for errors before the changes are committed to my server (DigitalOcean)

TO me, a **[`pre-commit` hook](https://git-scm.com/book/gr/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#_committing_workflow_hooks)** is a script which will execute before you commit *locally* in your repo. If "locally" is DigitalOcean, then yes, you are correct.
But if *locally* is on your machine *before pushing to* DigitalOcean, then no: a remote repo is not involved: that script is executed before a commit, and the fact that you push (or not) has no influence.

And don't forget that a [`pre-commit` hook can be skipped entirely](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7230886/6309) anyway with

```
git commit --no-verify
# or
git commit --n
```

What that script does is anything you want.

That being said, you can see a [pre-commit hook example with Django here](https://gist.github.com/venkatesh22/5972749).

Comment: So lets assume there are three layers: 1. Locally (Offline repo) | 2. Bitbucket | 3. Digital Ocean (Remote server). Am I correct in saying the pre-commit would happen before I commit from my Local offline repo to my Bitbucket repo?

Comment: @Zorgan a pre-commit is purely a *local* operation, local to your local repo. There is no "to another repo": a commit (and its pre-commit hook) is not concerned with the existence of a remote repo: it has no notion of a remote repo. You can have a pre-commit hook in a local repo with no remote repo at all.

Comment: @Zorgan When you have several "layers", and want to enforce a policy, a pre-ceive server-side hook (https://git-scm.com/book/gr/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#_server_side_hooks) is more appropriate: you can commit, but won't be able to push because the remote server-side will reject the commit.

Comment: So the pre-commit of the local repo is performed on itself? I thought the pre-commit only executes before you commit to another repo (e.g. Bitbucket)? How exactly do you perform the pre-commit on the same repo?

Comment: @Zorgan "committing to another repo" would be in your case "pushing your local commits to that other repo". And pushing is not mandatory after a pre-commit hook and a commit (both done on the local repo). You can do many commit before deciding to push anywhere.

Comment: @Zorgan "How exactly do you perform the pre-commit on the same repo": a pre-commit hook is *always* performed on the same repo: a commit is a local operation, local to your local repo. It lives in your `/path/to/local/repo/.git/hooks/pre-commit` file.

Comment: Thanks. I've added the hook file however I'm not sure how to actually execute it? I've performed `git commit` however it didn't indicate to me that the pre-commit hook worked.

Comment: @Zorgan Add an echo command in your pre-commit hook: you will see it executed (make sure the script is executable)