# Is there a way to bypass a git post-commit hook?

Tags: git

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7230820/skip-git-commit-hooks) works nicely with bypassing the precommit hooks, but the best way to skip the pre-commit seems to disable it with something like this:

```
gitdir="$(git rev-parse --git-dir)"
hook="$gitdir/hooks/post-commit"

# disable post-commit hook temporarily
[ -x $hook ] && chmod -x $hook

git commit -a -m "Commit all changes for testing. Will be reverted automatically"

# enable it again
chmod +x $hook
```

Took from [here](https://coderwall.com/p/dv-dgg/bypass-post-commit-hook-temporarily).

The question is - is there a way to do it better?

The reason for my doubts is that disabling the hook by removing execution rights seem a non-natural way of preventing something to run. After checking the web I found a natural way of skipping `pre-commit` case - we can just provide an option for git to skip the check. Basically, my question is if we have anything similar, or more or less accepted way of doing the thing.

Comment: I voted to close this, and could easily have said "opinion based" or "unclear what's being asked" - at least as it's written.  "Better" by what standard?  If you have a working solution but want another solution you need to clarify why

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger, good point. I will update my question

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger, could you please check the edited answer and tell, if it makes more sense now?