# Git pre-commit hook configuration

Tags: git, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit.com

I'm following the [office guidance](https://pre-commit.com) to create and add a hook to the pre-commit check process. There are 3 files I need to create

```
  .pre-commit-config.yaml

  .pre-commit-hooks.yaml

   theCheckFile.sh
```

The **config** file configs the **hooks** file which calls the **theCheckFils.sh** file to check my code style.

**Q.1** Where should I put those files? I currently put them into my project folder, and edit the .gitignore file to ignore all of them, any better suggestion? or this is OK.

**Q.2** The rev is needed in pre-commit-config.yaml file, where should I find this information, there is not version information from the code Repo I'm currently working with, can I just randomly create a number?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) These files seem like project-root files to me (though I've never used this tool myself). I'd suggest putting them at the project folder to start with (likely next to your .gitignore file). Add them to .gitignore if you want to be the only person using pre-commit on your team, or add them to the repo if your entire team will be using pre-commit with the same settings.

2) It looks like the repo's `rev` field is 'the revision or tag to clone at' of the repo with the *pre-commit* check code. This would be used to identify which version of the check code to use, so it would likely be required. https://pre-commit.com/#pre-commit-configyaml---repos