# sed: -e expression #1, char 10: unknown option to `s' in git on Windows

Tags: git

I am trying to do a simple git commit. I run

```
git add .
git commit -a -m "Added fixes"
```

and I get back

> sed: -e expression #1, char 10: unknown option to `s'

The solutions I see are for Linux, but unfortunately I'm on Windows (Corporate policy). How can I fix it?

This is the prepare-commit-msg

```
#!/bin/bash
# Include any branches for which you wish to disable this script
if [ -z "$BRANCHES_TO_SKIP" ]; then
BRANCHES_TO_SKIP=(master develop)
fi
# Get the current branch name and check if it is excluded
BRANCH_NAME=$(git symbolic-ref --short HEAD)
BRANCH_EXCLUDED=$(printf "%s\n" "${BRANCHES_TO_SKIP[@]}" | grep -c "^$BRANCH_NAME$")
# Trim it down to get the parts we're interested in
TRIMMED=$(echo $BRANCH_NAME | sed -e 's:\([a-z]\+\/\)*\([A-Z]\+-[0-9]\+\).\+:\2:')
# If it isn't excluded, preprend the trimmed branch identifier to the given message
if [ -n "$BRANCH_NAME" ] &&  ! [[ $BRANCH_EXCLUDED -eq 1 ]]; then
sed -i.bak -e "1s/^/$TRIMMED: /" $1
fi
```

Comment: There must be a commit hook in your repository, post it.

Comment: If there are hooks installed, you can skip them with https://stackoverflow.com/a/7230886/2295034

Comment: What's the name branch of your current branch? Does it contain `/`?

Comment: Fix/SolveCheckButton. It's not on the server yet

Comment: That's the problem. I get the same error on Linux with GNU sed.

Comment: Were you able to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that there is `/` in your branch name but the same character is used in `sed` script. As a temporary measure, you can replace `/` in sed script with something else, for example `,`:

```
sed -i.bak -e "1s,^,$TRIMMED: ," $1
```

In the ideal solution one should look for `/` in branch name and escape it correctly inside `sed` script.

Comment: the / is really important (Jira generated branches). Any idea how I can escape it?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Using the suggested solution you will be able to create a commit and commit message will contain `Fix/SolveCheckButton:` prefix.

Comment: When dealing with pathnames, rather than a `,` sed-`s`-arg separator I like to use `:`

Comment: Why `:` specifically?

Comment: Because it's at least conventionally reserved in all filesystems I know of.

Comment: On Windows, perhaps. You can easily create a file with a colon in its name on `ext4`  on Linux.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk that's true, but the colon is for instance used as a separator in all or almost all pathame lists, e.g. `$PATH` is a colon-separated list of directory names, and that's just the top of a long list of commonly-used examples.