# npm run deploy ignore hooks

Tags: reactjs, git, github-pages, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit.com

I was getting below error while committing the changes.

[image]

Simply adding `.pre-commit-config.yaml` file or deleting `.git\hooks` folder was not resolving my problem. So I added `--no-verify` option while committing and it solved my problem.

Now, I am trying to deploy my react app to Github Pages. When I run `npm run deploy` I get the same error as shown in the below picture.

[image]

How I can add `--no-verify` option while `npm run deploy`? Simply adding `.pre-commit-config.yaml` file or deleting `.git\hooks` folder is not resolving the problem.

I don't want to try `pre-commit uninstall` command because the command might uninstall the `pre-commit` globally.

Is there any alternative to disable the hooks locally specific to the current repository?

**Edit:**
I tried `pre-commit uninstall` as well. Still throws the same error when I do `npm run deploy`.

Comment: What is the content of `c:\dev\react-apps\find-my-event\.git\hooks`?

Comment: `hooks` folder contains only `pre-commit` file.

Comment: as in "`pre-commit.sample`" or "`pre-commit`"? Because if you rename `pre-commit` in `pre-commit.xxx`, you will desactivate it.

Comment: It is "`pre-commit`"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That message should come from `c:\dev\react-apps\find-my-event\.git\hooks\pre-commit`

For testing, you can rename `pre-commit` to `pre-commit.old` and see if the `npm run deploy` is still affected by the same error message.

That being said, if you are using the [`pre-commit/pre-commit`](https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit) python frmaework for managing and maintaining multi-language pre-commit hooks., then [issues 457](https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit/issues/457) cleary states:

> You need one of those to tell pre-commit what hooks you want to run.
> To see how to configure one, see http://pre-commit.com

For instance, [at a minimum](https://pre-commit.com/#quick-start):

> - Create a file named `.pre-commit-config.yaml`
> - you can generate a very basic configuration using [`pre-commit sample-config`](https://pre-commit.com/#pre-commit-sample-config)

Comment: After executing `pre-commit uninstall`, `.git\hooks\pre-commit` file get deleted. but still throws the same error on `npm run deploy`.

Comment: @aagjalpankaj OK. I dod not realize you were using https://pre-commit.com/. I have edited my answer.