# Can/should I use a pre-commit written in python to request people to respect a certain workflow?

Tags: python, git, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit

I want that if someone add modification to a .tex, it must have is .pdf version compiled.

I've been interested in using Pre-commit with hooks to request people to respect a certain workflow.

To be clear, I want that if someone add modification to a .tex, it must have his .pdf version compiled to ensure that everyone can look at the file at a glance. I've done some search about pre-commit and they are always talking about using python, docker, ... Should I write a simple python script to put in my pre-commit ?

Thank you for anyone that can help me explain those things.
I wish you a good day or night wherever you are.

Comment: It's unclear in your wording whether you are asking how to implement the logic of the hook, or whether you just wanted to know if you could/should do it in "simple python". Based on the answer you accepted, I'll assume the later and edit your question so it doesn't confuse people doing searches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I've done some search about pre-commit and they are always talking about using python, docker

You can use any program/scripting language you want, as long as:

- your `repo/.git/hook/pre-commit` file is an executable
- you have a way to distribute/update that hook for every user of your repository
- you understand a [client-side hook can be bypassed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7230886/6309)